Verification of Evan's representation formula $e^{-itB(y)}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\Gamma e^{-itz}(zI - B(y))^{-1}dz$ for $t$ independent $B(y)$
At the end of chapter 7.3 of Evan's PDE book, Evans states that if $B(y) = \sum_{j=1}^n y_jB_j$ for constant matrices $B_j$ and $\Gamma = \partial B(0,r)$ where $B(0,r)$ is a ball centered at zero in the complex plane with radius $r$ so large that $B(0,r)$ contains all eigenvalues of $B(y)$, then we have the representation formula
$$e^{-itB(y)}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\Gamma e^{-itz}(zI - B(y))^{-1}dz$$
This formula comes out of the blue, but luckily Evans provides a proof for it. Unluckily, Evans does nothing to motivate the intermediary steps he takes. For example, at first, Evans wants to verify that if $A(t,y)$ is the RHS of the identity, i.e. the integral expression, then
$$B(y)A(t,y)x = -\frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{dt}A(t,y)x$$
for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^m$. He does this by writing:
$$B(y)A(t,y)x = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\Gamma e^{-itz}B(y)(zI - B(y))^{-1}dz\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$B(y)A(t,y)x = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\Gamma e^{-itz}\left(z(zI - B(y))^{-1}x - x\right)dz\Longleftrightarrow$$
as $\int_{\Gamma}e^{-itz}dz = 0$. Sure, we can add/subtract zeroes all we like since $\Gamma$ is a closed loop and $e^{-itz}$ is holomorphic. But 1.) Why can we pass $B(y)$ inside the integral? This might be just a definition thing; it has been a some time since I've had to work with multivariate integrals. 2.) Why are
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\Gamma e^{-itz}B(y)(zI - B(y))^{-1}dz$$
and
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\Gamma e^{-itz}\left(z(zI - B(y))^{-1}x - x\right)dz$$
equal to each other?
Similar trickery happens a bit later when Evans writes that
$$A(0, y)x = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma}(zI - B(y))^{-1}xdz = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma}\frac{x + B(y)(zI - B(y))^{-1}}{z}dz$$
I have no clue why this equality holds.


The integral commutes with bounded linear operators in the sense that if $T : X \to Y$ is linear bounded and $f : E \to X$ and $T \circ f : E \to Y$ are integrable over $E \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ (for example if $f$ is continuous on a compact set) then:
$$T\left(\int_E f(x) \mathrm{d}x\right) = \int_E T(f(x)) \mathrm{d}x$$
But this means that you can get "creative" with the choice of $T$: for example you can choose an evaluation map on bounded operators $T : A \in B(V, W) \mapsto A(v_0) \in W$ or, in this case, $T : A \in M_k(\mathbb{R}) \mapsto AB \in M_k(\mathbb{R})$ or respectively $BA$.

I don't know which definition of this integral you use but the result I mentioned looks like something that'd be classic, I hope at least. In my case I like to define the integral by taking the unique vector which lets you swap the classic Lebesgue integral and elements of the dual space when such a vector exists, in which case the result above is fairly straightforward.

This is just using the fact that $(zI - C)(zI - C)^{-1} = I$ (by definition) hence $z(zI - C)^{-1} - I = C(zI - C)^{-1}$, among other rearrangements of the terms.

